# When creating a blog post through the WYSIWYG editor, text is not being wrapped in <p> tags correctly when starting with a link

Tags: wysiwyg

When creating a new blog post, and the first item is a link follewed by text like this:

`<a>Some link</a> some text`

When this is rendered into HTML The

tags get placed at the end of the text like this:

`<a>Some link</a> some text<p></p>`

If there is any text before the link at the beginning then

tags are wrapped correctly.

I have gone into wp-includes/formatting.php and am not able to find source of this problem...

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will helpful for you
1) There will be no p tag will wrap while starting with anchor tag. The editor will takes a each paragraph in a paragraph tag.(Whether it may any tag, the editor will all the html content inside of p tag) 
2) If you are using wordpress default post editor means just print it by using [the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) or [get_the_content($post_id)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) .
3) If you are using Custom Field (ACF) means use [apply_filters()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/).

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', 'your_field_name');?>
```

Comment: hi, just using standard get_the_content(). It's very strange cause if I add link at start of second paragraph it surrounds the whole block in <p> tags. Seems to just be the first paragraph...